# Mattermost app Error in mutex.h file: Config.h file not found Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.1, mattermost

[image]

I am using this github code.
https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-mobile

I am getting this error "config.h file not found" in mutex.h file. I am using MacOS High sierra 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.1. In glog-0.3.5 folder I have already done the following solution.

1- Close Xcode.

2- cd /node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5

3- Run ./configure

4- Run make

5- Run make install

6- Open Xcode and try building the Project.

in result of that glog folder showing config.h file in it but when I compile the project in Xcode it removed again from the glog folder. And Xcode is giving the same error that config.h file not found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed glog folder from mattermost app and add a new glog folder in the directory by creating a new react native project and replace it with the old glog folder in mattermost code's directory. It worked for me.